# How bind data to view without ModelAndView object

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have Spring Controller, and a method like this:

```
public ModelAndView getItems() {  

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("myView");
    Item entity = new Item();
    mav.addObject("myData", entity);   

    return mav;
}
```

So I want this data in myView.jsp.

I know if returning type is string, View name will implicity named the valur of string. But I don't know how to bind data to model.

I want to rewrite this method with String returning type instead of ModelAndView.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it works like this

**Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping("/tryThis")
public String tryThis(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("foo", "bar");
    return "viewName";
}
```

**JSP:**

```
<c:out value="${foo}" />
```

**Reference:**

- [15.3.2.3. Supported handler method
  arguments and return types](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-arguments)

Answer (score 2):

In your example the view name will be `myView`.jsp, and the Item object is aviable under the name `myData`  (`<c:out value="${myData}" />`)

Comment: Ok, but i want to set myData in other way. And i cannot understand how

Comment: @user643245: "I want to rewrite this method with String returning type instead of ModelAndView." - now your question making sense -> Sean Patrick Floyd is right

Answer (score 0):

You can use the @ModelAttribute on a method on your controller. The return value of the method will be bound to the named attribute in the Model.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib